# Html.DropownlistFor with editablefield

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm using a dropdownlistfor that populates some data from the database, the idea is that i want that the default value of the dropdown, has to be editable.

So the user can submit one of the options that are populated from the database, or the default one modified

How can i make this?

Comment: It sounds like you don't want a drop down list.  You want a combo box.  I know Telerik makes one (http://demos.kendoui.com/web/combobox/index.html) but it's not free.  There are potentially jQuery plugins that achieve the same effect as well (http://jquery.sanchezsalvador.com/page/jquerycombobox.aspx).  But a normal drop down list (`select` element) does not provide this functionality.

Comment: I know that doesnt provide this functionality, but i suppose that adding some jquery or something like that i can accomplish this function. The combobox jquery is not useful because i cant edit the fields. 
Any other idea?

Comment: How about jQuery UI Autocomplete?: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: was the first option that i used, but is not valid, because you cant edit a existing register,because when you change focus the changes mades are lost, is only usefull to filter

Comment: It sounds like you're looking to custom-build a component then.  (Unless you buy one like the Telerik one.)  Stack Overflow can certainly help with any issues you encounter while building it, of course.  But in the context of this question, it's not really answerable other than to say "that component doesn't provide that functionality."

Answer (score 0):

You could use an onclick event on the first value that triggers a jquery pop-up with a textfield which could rewrite your first value of the dropdown on submit.

Comment: is an option, but is not what I want